# Why does trying to build a kernel module give me a "-1 Unknown symbol" error?

Tags: drivers, kernel, kinect

I recently purchased a Kinect for Windows and quickly discovered that the camera drivers included in linux kernel 3.0+ aren't compatible with the Kinect for Windows hardware revision. After looking at the source code it seems like a tiny modification is all that is required for compatibility, so I've been trying to recompile the driver - to no avail.

I've been referring to [this article](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/compiling-linux-kernel-module.html) and [this one as well](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/build-linux-kernel-module-against-installed-kernel-source-tree.html), though they are a bit outdated.

When I try to compile the module, I get an error because the header file "gspca.h" can't be found in the include path. I located the missing header in my filesystem, but the file itself is empty. I've also tried downloading the kernel source (3.2.0-24-generic), which allowed me to compile the module, but when I load the module I get an error.

```
-1 Unknown symbol in module
```

Is there a standard way to go about this without first building the kernel? Will building the kernel ensure that I can build the module?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a standard way to go about this without first building the kernel? Will building the kernel ensure that I can build the module?

- If you get that error, **no**. You can force-load the module, and it will most probably work, but you won't be able to debug it and this method is not recommended.
- The error occurs because you're missing the `module.symvers` module symbol database.
- The *only* proper way to generate that file is to execute a full build of the kernel -- this *will* let you build the module.
- Be very careful to configure the kernel exactly to stock specifications unless you intend to install and run on the built kernel.